# Paperclip, PDF thumbnails and IE8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using paperclip and generating thumbnails for uploaded pdf's. They work fine except for when viewed in IE8. Anyone know why this is?

```
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :thumb => "140x140>" }

  validates_attachment :file, presence: false,
                              content_type: { content_type: "application/pdf" },
                              size: { less_than: 3.megabytes }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this by adding jpg as the default thumbnail image.

```
has_attached_file :file, :styles => { :thumb => ["140x140>", :jpg] }
```